# how to swap the image and back (right away) when checkbox checked?

Tags: checkbox

I am looking for the javascript that change (image1) to (image2) and then back to (image1) right away when checkbox checked.

I have  a code that swap the image when i checked the checkbox and going back to original image when checkbox is unchecked. But I want to change image and going back to original image right way when it checked. Can anyone help?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changePic(){
if (document.form1.check.checked){
document.picture.src="Images/industry_mrt.jpg";
document.picture.src="Images/industry_ps.jpg";
}

else{
document.picture.src="Images/industry_mrt.jpg";
}}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="Images/industry_ps.jpg" id="picture" name="picture"> 
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="checkbox" onClick="changePic();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I believe your code does have the desired effect - changing the image and then going back to original image instantaneously when the checkbox is checked, but if you want to see this you will need to delay the return to the original image.

Try the below:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange(this);" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleChange(checkbox)
{
    if(checkbox.checked){
        document.picture.src="Images/industry_mrt.jpg";
        setTimeout(function(){document.picture.src="Images/industry_ps.jpg";}, 2000); // 2 Seconds.

    } else{
        document.picture.src="Images/industry_mrt.jpg";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: one more quick questions. What about having multiple checkboxs for same image? I need more than two checkboxs but same event for same image changed.

Comment: Are we talking about a single image still?

Comment: yes. those two image and same swap and back to original( but multiple checkbox)